# Обновление записей в таблице занимает много времени

Tags: oracle

Имеется скрипт на 1.5м отдельных апдейт команд, через SQL Plus и SQL девелопер простой вызов занимает чуть более суток выполнения по времени (клиент располагается на другой машине в локальной сети). Если перекинуть скрипт на сервер с СУБД и выполнить локально (через SQL Plus), выполнение занимает примерно 1.5 часа. Как можно ускорить выполнение скрипта, ведь обновление 1.5м записей не должно занимать так много времени? Перед выполнением скрипта, выключается автокоммит и таблица лочится.
У меня есть следующие идеи:

1. Возможно, проблема в network latency, то есть клиент (SQL Plus, SQL Developer) после вызова отдельной команды ожидает подтверждения её выполнения, из-за этого так долго выполняется скрипт. Есть ли возможность выполнить весь скрипт одной командой, батч или спул скрипта целиком в базу?
2. Вероятнее всего, если дропнуть все индексы, залить данные, пересоздать их -существенно ускорит вставку данных
3. Что произойдет, если создать процедуру, в тело которой вставить все апдейты и выполнить его? Что произойдет, если весь скрипт обернуть в тело анонимной процедуры и вызвать через клиент?

Как Вы решали данную проблему или какие советы можете дать?

Comment: А какие у вас вообще команды в этом скрипте? Что они делают? Возможно на вашу задачу следует посмотреть вообще с другой стороны

Comment: Все три варианта возможны, плюс к третьему я бы добавил, что 100500 одиночных апдейтов можно заменить одним мерждем. Но без DDL таблиц и примеров команд из скрипта обсуждать нечего.

Comment: @Viktorov  в скрипте просто 1.5 миллиона строк вида: UPDATE <tableName> SET <ColumnName> = <Value>;

Comment: Предлагаю рассмотреть вариант их загрузки во временную таблицу например с помощью SQLLoader'a или через дам, с последующим Merge

Comment: @DaysLikeThis В таком виде это несколько бессмысленно, видимо, там что-то вроде `UPDATE <tableName> SET <ColumnName> = <Value> WHERE <ID_COLUMN> = <ID_VALUE>;`?

Comment: @Dmitry да, вы правы, выше написал немного неправильно :) с помощью SQL девелопера в анонимной функции обновление произошло на порядок быстрее